# How do I pass an list of strings as a query parameter in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

I have made an API GET endpoint that takes in a list of strings and am trying to expose it to APIM. 
How can I pass in the string to the endpoint from APIM and what transformations from the request needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

This hugely depends on the request format your back-end expects.

Let's assume you want to have a GET operation like `/multivalues?parm1=11&parm1=22` and you need to convert it into a JSON-array for a POST operation body. Providing parameters in this format would allow you to extract multiple values as string array and then transform it into some other array:

```
    <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-body template="none">var body = new JObject();
            string[] arrayOfStrings = (string[])context.Request.Url.Query["parm1"];
            var parameterArray = new JArray();
            foreach(string value in arrayOfStrings)
            {
                var parm1 = new JObject();
                parm1["name"] = "parm1";
                parm1["value"] = value;                    
                parameterArray.Add(parm1);
            }
            body["parameters"] = parameterArray;
            return body.ToString();</set-body>
```

But you could also have your own delimiter in one string like `/multivalues?parm2=11,22`:

```
    <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-body template="none">var body = new JObject();
            string[] arrayOfStrings = (string [])context.Request.Url.Query["parm2"];
            string[] subArrayOfStrings = arrayOfStrings[0].Split(',');
            var parameterArray = new JArray();
            foreach(string value in subArrayOfStrings)
            {
                var parm2 = new JObject();
                parm2["name"] = "parm2";
                parm2["value"] = value;                    
                parameterArray.Add(parm2);
            }
            body["parameters"] = parameterArray;
            return body.ToString();</set-body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kai's answer, if you want after transformations to call some external endpoint you can use the send-request policy. For example, you can perform:

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenstate" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
<set-url><EXTERNAL URL HERE></set-url>
<set-method>POST</set-method>
<set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
  <value>application/json</value>
</set-header>
<set-body template="none">var body = new JObject();
        string[] arrayOfStrings = (string[])context.Request.Url.Query["parm1"];
        var parameterArray = new JArray();
        foreach(string value in arrayOfStrings)
        {
            var parm1 = new JObject();
            parm1["name"] = "parm1";
            parm1["value"] = value;                    
            parameterArray.Add(parm1);
        }
        body["parameters"] = parameterArray;
        return body.ToString();</set-body>
</send-request>
```